# << Oracle regexp_replace special character string >>

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to replace the word contains special character with below format, need to replace with a another string. below are the sql's am trying to achieve, but somehow struck. Can you help to assist.

Format -> `_$deleted$73$0`
Expected Output -> `I01`

```
SQL> select REGEXP_REPLACE('_$deleted$73$0 RRR SSS','_\$deleted\$+?','I01') from dual ;

REGEXP_REPLACE('_$DE
--------------------
I0173$0 RRR SSS
```

But expected output:

```
I01 RRR SSS
```

Regards
Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original attempt does not work because part `\$+?` in the regexp means to match one or several successive `$`, which apparently is not what you want.

What exactly defines the "word to be replaced" ? From your example I assume it means any sequence that starts with `_$deleted`, followed by any sequence of non-space characters. In that case, use the regexp `_\$deleted\S*` (where `\S` matches a non-space character).

Answer (score 0):

to match all you can use

you need to match exactky the pattern

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('_$deleted$73$0 RRR SSS','_\$deleted\$.*\$0','I01') from dual ;
```

| REGEXP_REPLACE('_$DELETED$73$0RRRSSS','_$DELETED$.*$0','I01') |
| --- |
| I01 RRR SSS |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qm96nSj6)